# cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver in selenium webdriver with java, how to overcome from this?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying this code but it fails

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

  public class Fijan {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:Users\\Devrepublic\\Documents\\fijan\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("");
    }
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver

```
at prac.Fijan.main(Fijan.java:12)

 how to overcome from this problem
```

Comment: How did you add the jar ?

Comment: Thanks, i added jar files in module path before, just remove it from there and again add jars in class path, it works file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chromedrive path should end with extension of the driver.

So, change your line as below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:Users\\Devrepublic\\Documents\\fijan\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```